# Putting info on web server and then pulling info with Xcode

Tags: ios, database, xcode

I would like to hold info about restaurants - address, phone number, etc. - on a web server and then use that info in an iOS app. What do I need to know in order to do this? In other words, how do I format this info on the web server and then how do I pull the info?

Not everything needs to be explained to me here but I just don't know what to search for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `web service` to return data as `JSON`, `PLIST` or `XML` format, then the mobile application will make a call to this `web service` and `parse` the formatted data.

[Here](http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/) is a tutorial that will guide you from web service creation to the consuming (get data from the mobile application)

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/02/12/accessing-the-cloud-from-cocoa-touch/) a starting point. It describes how to make web requests to a server. You'll need to implement the server side as well.